# Error: method deserialize has 1 parameter but invoked with 2 arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code is like this

```
    using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public class SaveData : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string jsonString = String.Empty;

        context.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
        using (var inputStream = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
        {
            jsonString = inputStream.ReadToEnd();
        }

        var javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        object serJsonDetails = javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(jsonString, typeof (object));

        // You can now add logic to work with serJsonDetails object
    }
}
```

Everything looks okay to me, I have no Idea why this throws this error

```
Error: method deserialize has 1 parameter but invoked with 2 arguments
```

[image]

Comment: Error message isn't clear?

Comment: @SonerGönül To make it clear, I have added a screen

Comment: That method is expecting one parameter and you're providing two?

Comment: We can retype the message being displayed in the screenshot, but it doesn't get much clearer than that. It takes 1 parameter, not 2.

Comment: @ChrisL No, That method can accept multiple parameters

Comment: @Athul is right - according to MSDN this method has an overload.  The first method is `Deserialize<T>(string)` and the second is `Deserialize(string, Type)`:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191864%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is very clear : the Deserialize method has only one parameter (http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb355316(v=vs.110).aspx). But, you are calling the method with two parameters.

If you want to resolve this error, change :

```
object serJsonDetails = javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(jsonString, typeof (object));
```

to :

```
object serJsonDetails = javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(jsonString);
```

EDIT : Which version of .NET Framework did you use ? (the method with 2 arguments was appeared in .NET Framework 4 http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ee191864(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: it throws new error.
Error 9 The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<T>(string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. C:\.....\SaveData.cs 24 33

Comment: Try object serJsonDetails = javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<object>(jsonString);

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
   object serJsonDetails = javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(jsonString);
```